# Тире в сложном предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Можно ли так расставлять тире?
"О том, что если дать изобретению ход, то неразбиваемое стекло окажется дороже золота его казны – казна обесценится – цена золота упадет до цены песка, из которого делают стекло".

Comment: @Alenka, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше так:"О том, что если дать изобретению ход, то неразбиваемое стекло окажется дороже золота его казны , казна обесценится – цена золота упадет до цены песка, из которого делают стекло".

Два тире, думаю, излишни при трёх действиях, появляется видимость пояснения, чего здесь нет , смысл запутывается. Второе тире передаёт следствие первых двух действий. Вместо тире возможна и запятая, тогда будет передана последовательность событий.

Comment: А может быть "... стекло окажется дороже золота казны - казна обесценится и цена золота упадет до цены песка, из которого делают стекло". А вообще такая постановка тире возможна? Нигде не вижу правила, а там есть еще похожий случай: "Директор не поверил – попытался разбить стакан – не разбивается". 
Тоже самое. Автор, видимо любил расставлять тире... Но допустимо ли это вообще?!

Comment: Возможно и так. Видимо, допустимо и два тире, но это уже будет авторская пунктуация.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем предложении тире служит для выделения причинно-следственных отношений. Количество тире зависит от смысла предложения. Как такового правила о двойном тире нет. Первый вариант: вследствие подорожания стекла - золото казны обесценится и цена золота упадет .... Здесь одна причина - подорожания стекла. Два тире будут обозначать две причины. Т.е.(1) подорожания стекла - обесценение казны,  (2) обесценение казны - упадок цены золота( из-за обесценения казны, а не из-за подорожания золота). Выбор за вами.